# SQL Query to get top 2 records of group

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a following Input Table

```
Source  EventType
A        X
A        X
A        X
A        Y
A        Y
A        Z
B        L
B        L
B        L
B        L
B        M
B        N
B        N
```

Expected output

```
Source    EventType   Frequency
A          X            3
A          Y            2
B          L            4
B          N            2
```

How to form a SQL query to get the result as shown above ?
I was able to achieve results but with just one source at a time.

```
select TOP 2 eventype, count(*) as frequencey
from myEventTable 
where source = 'A'
group by eventtype
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Source, EventType, COUNT(*) as Frequency,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Source ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM myEventTable
    GROUP BY Source, Eventtype
)

SELECT Source, EventType, Frequency
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

[image]

### Demo

The reason this works is that `ROW_NUMBER` is applied *after* the `GROUP BY` operation completes, i.e. it runs against the groups.  We can then easily limit to the top 2 per source, as ordered by frequency descending.